# How to change captured video file name through user input before uploading to server in android?

Tags: android, file, filenames, user-input

I want to change file name before going to upload to server.
Please help me out of this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you sending it to server? Do you have a File object?

Comment: You could also change it once it reaches the server hence making your android app do less work

Answer (score 0):

Actually You can just ask user for the name and append the new name to the directory path. Here is the example program .

```
          File oldName = new File("C:/program.txt");
          File newName = new File("C:/java.txt");
          if(oldName.renameTo(newName)) {
             System.out.println("renamed");
          } else {
             System.out.println("Error");
          }
```